# Salesforce Custom Currency Conversion Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, multi-currency

I need a little help . I am almost there ... but need a little hand-holding. Agenda is to ALWAYS display the value converted in EUR - does not matter what the record currency is.

I am using this code below:

```
trigger convertToEuro on CustomObject(before update) { 
    List<CurrencyType> currencyTypeList = [select id,IsoCode,ConversionRate from CurrencyType where isActive = true] ;

    Map<String , Decimal> isoWithRateMap = new Map<String, Decimal>();

    for(CurrencyType c : currencyTypeList) {

        isoWithRateMap.put(c.IsoCode , c.ConversionRate) ;

    }



    for(CustomObject ce: trigger.new){

        if(ce.CurrencyIsoCode != 'EUR' && isoWithRateMap.containsKey(ce.CurrencyIsoCode)){

            ce.Amount_Converted__c = ce.ffps_iv__Amount__c/ isoWithRateMap.get(ce.CurrencyIsoCode);

        }

    }
}
```

It is doing everything fine except the fact that the Amount_Converted__c field's values are displayed as USD (& EUR) but EUR seems like display only value - the USD is what the Amount_Converted__c field is holding. I want to use Amount_Converted__c converted in EUR in my workflow but instead I am getting the USD value - how could I just get the EUR value? I don't really need the Record Currency type - I need my EUR currency to be used in my workflows/approvals.

[image]

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are doing things like this (manual conversion of currency fields), the target of the conversion (`Amount_Converted__c`) needs to be of type Number, not type Currency.

When it is a currency type, SFDC OOTB rules for how currencies are displayed are governed by the record's currency and the user's currency.

When I've done what you are doing in the past, I've named my custom field `Amount_EUR__c` to be explicit about what the field's content contains.

Of course, another option you might consider is to make your org's currency = EUR - this way, all reports and dashboards will roll up currencies to EUR automatically.

Comment: I did the number field and then it would not even convert at all - not sure why. It would show 472,768.00 - if after converting the field type to number it would show 440,891.54 I would be okay. But it does not, not sure why though? 

Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: @steve - I find this hard to believe; internally, numbers and currency types are both expressed as Decimal

Comment: @Cropedy - I was wrong - and you were right. It does convert and thanks for the help. The above code does not need any change - it is perfect the way it is.

Comment: @steve - as a courtesy to the community, if the answer addressed the issue, please mark as answered.

Comment: @Cropedy: Can you help me in writing a test class for this, please?

Comment: @steve -- best practice here is to post a new question and show your progress to date - this way folks in the community at large can help and the specifics of how to test & mock `currencyType` can be discussed for everyone to benefit

Comment: Thanks @cropedy - quick question can we show up rates based on particular date? If yes, how do i go about modifying? So, I need to isoWithRateMap.put(c.IsoCode , c.ConversionRate) and put the c.ConversionRate based on a date

Comment: Steve - given that your code isn't posted here, hard to be definitive - but the conversion can certainly be based on some rate as of a date - you are going to be invoking from apex so you should be fine